# ¿Cómo optimizar el rendimiento en BD Oracle, manteniendo llaves foráneas?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, rendimiento, indices, constraints

Tengo un modelo relacional con varias entidades y relaciones. Por el gran volumen de datos que se maneja, las inserciones se demoran exponencialmente a medida que aumenta el tamaño de la tabla (por el recálculo de índices) y me han propuesto quitar las restricciones (constraint) y no solo desactivarlas. Para mantener la documentación explícita en la BD, es preferible mantener estas restricciones, porque si no aparecerían decenas de tablas sueltas, independientes, cuando en realidad no es así.

**¿Es posible mantener las restricciones (constraint) sin afectar el rendimiento de inserciones?**

Comment: Usar las restricciones como documentacion suena a una muy mala idea. Para eso existen documentos que pueden decir como se relacionan las tablas en una base de datos. y si las reglas de negocios cambias, es mas costoso hacer los cambios en la base de datos. Igual esta pregunta es demasiado basada en opiniones, yo siempre opine que la db debe ser un conjunto de tablas limpias (sin nada que implique relaciones entre ellas). o sea, no guardar constrain en la DB.

Comment: @gbianchi es cierto que existen documentos como el modelo de negocios, pero en estos tiempos que los dba no quieren documentar, es simple realizar ingeniería inversa y tener el modelo actualizado, similar ocurre con el código fuente y la generación de documentación (javadoc en Java, por ejemplo). Además, el modelo relacional incluye tablas y relaciones, así que prescindir de las relaciones es como continuar usando Excel o archivos de texto. El diseño de la BD tiene que estar correcto, normalizado si procede, no puede ser solo almacenamiento.

Comment: Pasate por el [chat]. esto no tiene nada que ver con DBa. y estas confundiendo las cosas. La doc en codigo no afecta el rendimiento del mismo. y esto si. Es mas, los cambios en documentacion ni siquiera afectan al soft.

Comment: Y los dba no deben documentar, lo deben hacer los analistas del sistema que diseñaron el modelo de la DB

Comment: La pregunta es clara, demos tiempo a que pueda ser vista y respondida por alguien que conozca, saludos.

Comment: La pregunta es clara, de igual forma muy abierta a opiniones distintas :), lo que necesitas es una sugerencia sobre qué hacer con los constraints de tu base de datos, no es realmente una pregunta.